# Jasmine-node Body is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, jasmine-node

I am new to jasmine and attempting to run a basic test however I keep getting an error.

My testing is as follows

```
var request = require('request');
var base_url = 'http://localhost:8080'
var getdata = require('../modules/getdata.js')
var index = require('../index.js')
describe("GetData Test",function(){

describe("Get /", function() {
it("returns statusCode 200", function(done) {
  request.get(base_url, function(error, response, body){
    expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
    done();
  });
});
it("returns Api is Online", function(done) {
  request.get('base_url', function(error, response, body){
    console.log(request.body)
    expect(body).toBe("Api is online");
    index.closeServer();
    done();
  });
});
});
});
```

This code is testing the following Functions

```
server.get('/', getdata.test)
```

and getdata.test is the following

```
exports.test = function test(req, res) {
    res.send('Api is online')
};
```

The first test passes, as the responseCode is indeed 200. However the second tests errors as apparently the body is undefined. Any help? The error is as follows:

```
jack@JacksLaptop:~/workspace$ npm test

> jack_tidbury_web_api@1.0.0 test /home/jack/workspace
> jasmine-node spec

App running on port 8080
.undefined
F

Failures:

  1) GetData Test Get / returns Api is Online
   Message:
     Expected undefined to be 'Api is online'.
   Stacktrace:
     Error: Expected undefined to be 'Api is online'.
    at Request._callback (/home/jack/workspace/spec/getdata_spec.js:17:22)
    at self.callback (/home/jack/workspace/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Request.init (/home/jack/workspace/node_modules/request/request.js:274:17)
    at new Request (/home/jack/workspace/node_modules/request/request.js:128:8)
    at request (/home/jack/workspace/node_modules/request/index.js:54:10)
    at Function.get (/home/jack/workspace/node_modules/request/index.js:62:12)

Finished in 0.051 seconds
2 tests, 2 assertions, 1 failure, 0 skipped


npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You meant response `body` instead of `request.body`. Also, you are getting `'base_url'` instead of `base_url`. Try this:

```
it("returns Api is Online", function(done) {
  // Here you were getting 'base_url', which threw an error because that's not a valid url
  request.get(base_url, function(error, response, body){
    console.log(body); // Here you were logging request.body
    expect(body).toBe("Api is online");
    index.closeServer();
    done();
  });
});
```